# Putting in a sub ceiling in garage to insulate and dampen sound to upstairs bedroom

Tags: insulation, ceiling, joists, support

I am putting in a sub ceiling with insulation and drywall. I have begun the project and it kind of suddenly hit me that this weight could be dangerous? I'm running the 2x6x9.5 ft joists from these beams pictured. I plan to do it again on the back section. This is in my garage. Above garage is master bedroom. Middle beam Runs underneath middle of bedroom[[image: enter image description here][1]]
[Pic1[image: ][1]][image][image]

Comment: See past answers for explanation of why you want those 2x4's to not be touching the pre-existing ceiling (to keep them from coupling noise from one side to the other).

Comment: There's about a 5 inch gap from ceiling to joist

Comment: That should certainly address my concern

Comment: Any thoughts on the joists going between these 2 beams?

Comment: You should check out the ceiling joist table at [IRC R802.5.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch08_SecR802.5.1). Your design live load strength is 0 psf, and that table says that #2 2x4s are sufficient on 16" centers for your use case, and that's with an unnecessary 10 psf live load capacity. You can shave off some cost and weight by switching to the smaller ceiling joists, although you wouldn't be able to hang lots of weight from the ceiling.

Comment: I think 2x6 at 16" on center is fine- any smaller and they would probably sag. This is only supporting your ceiling- there is no floor load involved.

Comment: That ceiling joist table's L/Δ = 240 is the deflection limit for flexible ceiling finishes from IRC Table R301.7. In the context of the table at IRC R802.5.1, the deflection limit indicates that your 10 ft span under a 10 psf live load wouldn't sag more than 120"/240 = 0.5". Your ceiling's case of a 2.7 psf dead load with zero live load then implies a maximum sag of (0.5")(2.7psf)/(10psf) = 1/8". Reducing this sag with heavier, more expensive 2x6s is totally unnecessary. Save yourself a buck and use the 2x4s if you haven't already bought the 2x6s.

Comment: And you seem to have switched layout at a joist in the middle of the bay. This is usually ill-advised because then a ceiling panel's end misses a joist. As built, you might have to make an extra cut along the whole bay's width of ceiling panels. For the next bay, it might be wise to break layout at the end of a run of joists instead of at the middle.

Comment: The insulation I have is 15 inches so I've been measuring my gaps at 15 inches. When I ran my tape along the top to mark out 96 inches to center that beam for attaching the drywall that is where I landed. Perhaps I need to rethink this for the back section? I have even wondered if I shouldn't be running these joists wall too wall instead of between the beams.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the joist direction. It's not much load. Especially with 2x4s (2.3 psf instead of 2.7 psf). And often there's 3/4" floor sheathing with no underlayment to create a bit more excess dead load capacity.

Answer (score 2):

My quick computation for your added weight is 2.7 psf (neglecting insulation weight).

I would bet that your floor's dead load was spec'ed for 10 psf, so if you have a light floor finish like carpet, then you probably had some unused dead load capacity. For 1 psf carpet plus 1-1/8" plywood plus 2 psf floor framing plus 1/2" drywall, I get a total dead load of 7.9 psf. That hypothetical scenario would leave an unused capacity of 2.1 psf. That hypothetically is enough for most of the 2.7 psf of added weight.

Modern sleeping rooms get designed for 30 psf live load. I've seen a 1991 UBC (the western US's building code before today's national code) calling for 40 psf live load everywhere including the sleeping rooms. Assuming that there was no extra dead load capacity, the 2.7 psf of added weight would imply a live load capacity loss of 7% to 9%. In the hypothetical case of zero extra dead load capacity where the live load capacity is reduced by the full 7% to 9%, the extra dead load could possibly result in some out-of-spec floor sagging over a long time horizon.

Comment: Perhaps the OP should have oriented the "joists" the other direction?